# Can't connect to ubuntu 16.04 with tightvnc client

Tags: vnc

I have installed tightvnc on my ubuntu 16.04 desktop/server computer. I can ping it, connect using putty ssh. Start the vncserver successfully. From windows 10 pro workstation computer is start TightVNC viewer and enter the IPaddress of the ubuntu computer. I have tried putting VNC port 590x after the IPAddress as 192.168.n.n:Port#. In fact I have tried ever combinations found on internet on how to connect using viewer. This is simple setup. Any help someone can give me would be greatly appreciated.

Ben

Comment: Make sure the server is listening on external interfaces not just on the loopback (127.0.0.1) interface with `sudo netstat -nlpt | grep ':59..'` or the equivalent `ss` command. Also check that you don't have a firewall blocking the port.

Answer (score 0):

If your ssh connection maps the port 5900 to localhost::5900, the viewer invocation should look like:

```
xtightvncviewer localhost::5900
```

I cannot speak to the putty invocation, but from Ubuntu, I can invoke the remote x11vnc (on ip ...131) with the command:

```
ssh -t -L 5900:localhost:5900 192.168.1.131 'x11vnc -localhost  -display :0'
```

---

Include a  username if necessary.  If you don't have an X server running as that user, then try running

```
sudo ssh -t -L 5900:localhost:5900 192.168.1.131 'x11vnc -localhost -auth guess -display :0'
```

Comment: Enter the above command.  Get permission denied after enter the password set up for VNC.

Comment: Can you ssh/putty straight to your ssh server?  Get that working first, accept any certs. and then try the vnc connection.,